# how to return console data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This console log is working properly. How to get this data for the html.

**ProductController.js**

```
$scope.selectedProduct = function(product)
 {
    console.log(product.post_title);
    console.log(product.ID);
    console.log(product.post_date);
    console.log(product.post_author);
 }
```

**ProductDetails.html**

```html
<ion-item class="item widget uib_w_109 d-margins item-button-left" data-uib="ionic/list_item_button" data-ver="0">
        Product Name : {{product.post_title}} <br>
            Product Id : {{product.ID}}<br>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Would you like to fetch data from server then show that in HTML?

Comment: yes this data from server.

Comment: `<ion-item class="item widget uib_w_109 d-margins item-button-left" data-uib="ionic/list_item_button" data-ver="0">
        Product Name : {{selectedProduct.post_title}} <br>
            Product Id : {{selectedProduct.ID}}<br>
</ion-item>` use this

Comment: this answer also not working my friend. pls can you help me

Comment: Cab you show just result of console.log(product)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign to $scope variable,

```
$scope.selectedProduct = function(product)
 {
    $scope.product.post_title = product.post_title;
    $scope.product.ID = product.ID;
    ........
 }
```

if you want to push it to an array,

```
$scope.products =[];
$scope.products.push($scope.product);
```

Comment: `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.product.post_title = product.post_title') ` Now, I have this error

Comment: you need to declare the $scope.poduct variable initially, something like this  $scope.product = {};

Comment: how to set this data into array

Comment: $scope.products.push($scope.product);

Comment: give me team viewer

Answer (score 2):

Assign those values into a scope variable and try calling those scope variables in HTML.[image]

Comment: $scope.selectedProduct = function(product)
 {
    $scope.productPostTitle = product.post_title;
    $scope.productID = product.ID;

 }

Comment: is there any fiddle available for your problem?

Comment: `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.product.post_title = product.post_title')` Now I have this error

Comment: hope the image will help you!

Comment: can u post a snapshot of your code completely including html? else u could have create a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Just set the product passed as parameter to a scope variable, then bind or  use the scope variable in HTML.

here is a working plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/caqLK8oOIukeNuPQed3h?p=preview

```
  $scope.product = {};
  $scope.selectedProduct = function(product) {
    $scope.product.post_title = product.post_title;
    $scope.product.ID = product.ID;
    $scope.product.post_date = product.post_date;
    $scopee.product.post_author = product.post_author;

  };
```

in Plunker button gets the product from server and calls a function to set the product.
as plunker doesnt have server request the product to be fetched is defined statically.

Comment: This is not working my friend. This Plunker  also not working

Comment: sorry had version issues, please try again, i have updated the plunker, Run it and button click will fetch the values.

Comment: It will working on Plunker now. What I need to use for this my friend.  `productFetched`

Comment: @DRK the 'productFetched' variable is statically defined, you need to get the data from the server , which will update the product right?

Comment: How I can get data my friend. pls can you help me

Comment: you will need to do a xhr or http request to your backend. what are you using in backend?

Comment: I'm using PHP as a backend

Comment: i have updated the Plunker with a factory method which will contact with backend to get data. but as i dont have a backend have commented that line and returned a static object. try the approach in plunker. do acknowledge if it worked

Comment: Add to this last u did one also my friend. Please

Comment: Can u give me your mail address my friend. please

Comment: I sent mail my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this...

```
$scope.product{

}

$scope.selectedProduct = function(product)
{
    $scope.product.post_title = product.post_title;
    $scope.product.ID = product.ID;
    $scope.product.post_date = product.post_date;
     $scopee.product.post_author =product.post_author;
}
```

or you can simply do...

```
$scope.product{

}

$scope.selectedProduct = function(product)
 {
    $scope.product = product;
 }
```

Comment: `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.product.post_title = product.post_title')` Then I have this error

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the values in $scope variable and also need to mention ng-controller attribute in the parent element. Here is a full code with example

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app1">
 <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
  Employee Info<br/>
  <strong>Id:</strong> {{employeeId}}<br/>
  <strong>Name:</strong> {{employeeName}}
 </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('app1', []);
app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.employeeId= "E001";
    $scope.employeeName= "John Doe";
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've a single value then you can access that by using [0] upset else you can do it by using ng-repeat.

Please check following code.

```js
angular.module('appTest', [])
  .controller("repeatCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      Name: "Soap",
      Price: "25",
      Quantity: "10"
    }, {
      Name: "Bag",
      Price: "100",
      Quantity: "15"
    }, {
      Name: "Pen",
      Price: "15",
      Quantity: "13"
    }];
  
  $scope.result = {};
  $scope.selectProduct = function(product){
    $scope.result = product;
  };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="appTest">
  <section ng-controller="repeatCtrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:1">
          <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
            {{key}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
          <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
            <a href="#" ng-click="selectProduct(item)">{{val}}</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <div>
    Name : {{result.Name}} <br/>
    Price : {{result.Price}} <br/>
    Quantity : {{result.Quantity}}  
      
    </div>
  </section>
  
</body>
```

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: Do you've single value or multiple values in loop ?

Comment: In this link i have array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366856/what-is-wrong-in-angularjs-controller

Comment: I've updated my code, please check now. You can just replace the "title" with product.title and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118599/discussion-between-mohit-tanwani-and-drk).

Comment: You can just get the code what ever needed to you. like code for $scope.product..

I've given you the running example.

Comment: Change this code for that selectProduct function

$scope.selectedProduct = function(product) 
{ 
   $scope.product = [{
      post_title : product.post_title,
      product : product.ID,
      post_date : product.post_date,
      post_author : product.post_author
    }]; 
}

Comment: Please create full fiddle with HTML, I will check it

Answer (score 0):

Start by declaring a ´$scope´ variable :

```
$scope.product = {};
```

Then assign it a value in your fonction :

```
$scope.selectedProduct = function(product) {
    $scope.product.ID = product.ID;
   ... 
}
```

**EDIT**

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wor6gm15/) is working, is there any difference in your code?

Comment: `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.product.post_title = product.post_title')` Now I have this error my friend

Comment: It seems like your ´$scope´ isn't declared, what do you get when you do : ´console.log($scope)´ ?

Comment: i'm checking with safari browser my friend. pls can you help me,

Comment: Just write ´console.log($scope)´ in your function and paste the output here please.

Comment: `selectedProduct: function (product) {
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: ""` Showing like this

Comment: `users: Object
$$hashKey: "object:6"
name: "Arden Grange"
products: Array[3]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "object:29"
ID: "47"
post_author: "5"
post_date: "2015-10-20 16:13:04"
post_title: "Arden Grange, Premium"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
slug: "arden-grange"
term_id: "10"` Like this also showing

Comment: Also, what do you get when you do `console.debug(product)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118603/discussion-between-cedric-babeix-and-drk).

Comment: can you check chat pls

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript and html code as below:

**JS**

```
$scope.selectedProduct = function(product){
    return product;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item class="item widget uib_w_109 d-margins item-button-left" data-uib="ionic/list_item_button" data-ver="0">
    Product Name : {{selectedProduct.post_title}} <br>
    Product Id : {{selectedProduct.ID}}<br>
</ion-item>
```

Regards.

Comment: Please provide some info about error. or may be create fiddle to show that what you are trying out.

Comment: can you answer this question my friend.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431873/controller-data-set-another-page-in-angular